# Access Code of another virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Suppose I have two virtual directories under one application and I want to access functions and methods of another virtual directory in one directory. Is this possible and if yes then How ?

Answer (score 0):

using web-service or Http handler or WCF.

What do you mean by virtual directory.
Does it mean a hosted application.
If yes then above is the solution.

Otherwise If you know the physical path of the application
You can also use `reflection` to execute the method inside any `dll`

Comment: I am using asp.net 2.0 and iis7.0. Virtual directory means In IIS Sites-DefaultWebsite-virtal directories.

Comment: If i know physical path of class then how i call the functions os the class

Comment: @Saurabh do you have any `web-application` running with that `virtual directory` whose method you want to access.

Comment: Ya, we can also say that two web applications and set as different virtual directories in website. and i want to access class under App_Code of one into another ? Please help, its urgent.

Comment: do you have both the projects with you. If you have then add the reference of the first project in the second one. Or use reflection to execute the method inside the app_code method.